# Permission denied on running globally activated dart package

Tags: dart, command-line

I'm trying to develop a command line package so I followed these steps:

`dart  create --template=package-simple package_name`

then activating the package globally with:

`dart pub global activate --source path $(pwd)`

note that I didn't find anything in the documentation about `--source path actual_path` but whenever I use the command only with `--source actual_path` I get the following:

`"/Users/user/Desktop/Workspace/package_name" is not an allowed value for option "source".`

So after successfully activating the package I tried to run it using:

`package_name`

But I got this:

`zsh: command not found: package_name`

Found out that the documentation [here is outdated](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path) and after searching the local directory I found the actual directory is `global_packages` not `bin`, and so I've changed it.

Now when I try `package_name` I get:
`zsh: permission denied: package_name`

After investigation I found that `package_name` is a directory in the `global_packages` directory and it only contains `pubspec.lock` so I've tried `chmod a+x` on the  file and the directory with no avail.

Further investigation the `global_packages` contained another package `intl_utils` inside I found:

```
.packages       incremental
.dart_tool      bin             pubspec.lock
```

But running `intl_utils` on the terminal too get's me the same error:
`zsh: permission denied: intl_utils`
I didn't install the package manually but the VS Code extension Flutter Intl did and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Now I have two questions:

1. permission denied on what exactly since the Flutter Intl extension works perfectly???
2. I have a file in my package `bin/my_package.dart` but it didn't go there, am I doing something wrong?

I'm running dart through flutter:
Flutter (Channel master, 2.13.0-0.0.pre.90, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-x64, locale en-US)

`dart --version`

Dart SDK version: 2.17.0-202.0.dev (dev) (Thu Mar 10 20:55:41 2022 -0800) on "macos_x64"

## Edit #1

Tried `dart pub global run package_name` and it worked but it seems like it's building the package again, but still I need to use it without the long line the correct way.

## Edit #2

To create the app I've tried
`dart create -t console-full package_name` but still with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

So after messing around and changing the branch (a lot) turns out the problem is in the `pubspec.yaml` where there should be :

```yaml
executables:
  package_name: # you can add a custom path here if you want though
```

And I guess the docs were right about "bin" directory but it left me wondering about `global_packages` and `intl_utils`

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I ran into a similar issue, but already had the `package_name` declared in the yaml. It turns out that I had to delete the `.dart_tool/pub/bin` folder.

```bash
sudo rm -r ./.dart_tool/pub/bin
```

My guess is that I was running a previously cached build which was causing the issue.